# Saving information of a control in javascript app data

Tags: javascript, session, html, controls

I'll try and ask this as accurate as possible as I don't exactly understand my assignment.

Basically we had to create 3 HTML controls or JS controls and for each control we had to add an event handler that'd read something from a control and show it in a DIV.

Now my question is, how can I save the information shown in that DIV. I really don't understand how to do this. To be more specific, when I close the Build and re-open it after typing something in a textbox that would for example then give me the info from the textbox in a DIV, i'd want to see the same information I typed earlier in the Div again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) will suit your purposes.

Comment: Yea but how does that go? Like I have no experience in it. I read something about sessionState but I need an example.